# Algorithm for "Clustering" a directed graph

Tags: algorithms, graphs, optimization, clustering

I have a directed graph with unweighted edges between the vertices, and possible cycles.

I want an algorithm that I can pass in the graph and a number N, and have it spit out a set of N clusters each containing some of the vertices, such that:

1. Each vertex can only belong to one cluster
2. The total number of original-graph edges between the clusters is minimized
3. The original-graph edges between any pair of clusters flow only in one direction
4. The clusters themselves form a directed *acyclic* graph
5. The size of each cluster are as equal as possible

Note: The original graph can contain cycles, but i want the "graph of clusters" that gets generated to be acyclic.

E.g. given the graph defined by the following vertices (blue circles) and directed edges (blue arrows), given the target number of clusters `3`, the ideal clustering would be the green circles that would minimize the number of edges going between clusters and with the clusters themselves forming a directed acyclic graph.

[image]

What is this problem called? Is there an efficient solution? If not, are there any heuristics that I can use?

Comment: Conditions 3,4 are satisfied precisely when the nodes of each strongly connected component lie in the same cluster. Objective 2 is a weighted version of the [minimum k-cut problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_k-cut), while objective 5 is a case of [multiway number partitioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiway_number_partitioning). Both of those problems are NP-hard on their own, so trying to optimize some combination of them is likely to be NP-hard as well.

Comment: I don't think 3 and 4 are satisfied just by putting each strongly connected component in one cluster. 

Consider the graph with edges {A -> B, C -> D}. If we make our clusters {A, D}, and {B, C}, we end up with the two clusters have edges going in both directions, and the two clusters form a cycle, even though the individual vertices do not form any strongly connected components

Comment: True, it's not sufficient. I think it is still nessecary, though.

Comment: This is not yet a well-formed problem.  You list two optimization metrics that are in tension with each other: minimize number of cross-cluster edges; make sizes of cluster as equal as possible.  The solution that minimizes the number of cross-cluster edges might lead to inequal-sized clusters, and the solution that makes cluster sizes equal might not minimize cross-cluster edges.  You'll first need to figure out what is the objective metric you want to minimize.  You can only pick a metric, and you'll have to figure out how it takes into account both cross-cluster edges and cluster sizes.

Comment: @D.W. you're right, the problem isn't fully specified. I guess I'm looking for any prior art anywhere in this area that I can learn from. Even if it's just a phrase or keyword to google, I think that would be very useful to helping me find my way to a properly-defined problem and maybe even a solution